# Alternative for OpenID?

Tags: openid

Is there any alternative for OpenID,what i means is a site which provide our details fully, and we can log in to a site with that ID?
**Update**
suppose think that i am developing a site which have openID integration, i will have only a username not so much details,thats why i am asking

Comment: Why do you need an alternative?

Comment: Simple Need to start a new one, which having all the details of people to share

Comment: What do  you mean by "so much details"? OpenID without extensions allows you *only* to authenticate an identifier, without any... details.

Comment: @Mewp: think i am developing a Social Networking Site, you need to fill all the details na?? if i have a OpenDetails ID,which contain all the details and which will authenticate people, so that it is easy for both ends na?

Comment: Oh, I see. then there is no such system that you're looking for. You can request many attributes with openid, however you can't depend on them being sent. Generally, AX extension for OpenID is well suited for your needs, however most providers supply only few of AX attributes -- and of course, an user could just refuse to provide them.

Comment: Hey Mewp: thks for your info, can u post it as answer so that i can mark it as answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such system that you're looking for.

You can request many attributes with openid, however you can't depend on them being sent.
Generally, AX extension for OpenID is well suited for your needs, however most providers supply only few of AX attributes -- and of course, an user could just refuse to provide them.

Answer (score 4):

[IndieAuth](https://indieauth.com) is a "spiritual successor" to OpenID, with a very similar workflow for the end-user. It also supports *identity delegation*, a unique feature of OpenID 2.0.

But, it does not provide or enforce extra details from the user.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft touted their [CardSpaces technology](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480189.aspx) a few years back which iirc was OpenID like (amongst others).

Answer (score 0):

There is Facebook-Connect which provides a [Single-Sign-on](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web#login).

Answer (score 0):

[SAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language) could be what you are looking for..

Comment: Basically why SAML using for?

Answer (score 0):

You can use decentralized OpenID alternative EMCSSL: http://emercoin.com/EMCSSL

*Disclaimer:
I am author of this system.*